# Get max value of a row in table

Tags: mysql

Hi i am trying to get the row values having maximum of column name

Table main

```
id|days|week
1 |1   |1
2 |2   |4
3 |5   |1
4 |2   |3
5 |1   |4
6 |4   |1
7 |1   |2
8 |6   |2
```

Result Needed

```
id|days|week
2 |2   |4
3 |5   |1
4 |2   |3
8 |6   |2
```

I am using inner join with group by week .But the expected result returning wrong values

Comment: I'd suggest posting your attempts at a query as well.

Comment: You said `Get max value`. The result should be `8|6|2`. Why another rows also include in result set?

Comment: Explain the logic behind the result properly.

Comment: This question is asked endlessly. Sometimes it's correctly answered too.

Comment: The query is getting the row values  based on the maximum value in the week column that is the MAX(week) and its corresponding row values.

Answer (score -2):

Without more info this is all  I can do , I know its not the answer but we can expand on it.

```
Select  min(id),max(days) ,week
 from main 
group  by Week
```

You mention a join. Please post your query.

Comment: We cannot expand this. But we can delete it and start again!

Comment: Hi Daxmax, Thnks for your reply, this query is not valid for my requirement.If using this we can get multiple row values based on the week value